# adjoint operator of convolution operator

Tags: convolution, adjoint-operators

The definition of adjoint operator is defined as follows: suppose $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{Z}$ are Hilbert spaces, and $\mathcal{F}$ is a linear bounded operator mapping $\mathcal{V}$ to $\mathcal{Z}$, $\mathcal{F}^*$ is a linear bounded operator mapping 
$\mathcal{Z}$ to $\mathcal{V}$. We say $\mathcal{F}^*$ is the adjoint of $\mathcal{F}$, if 
$$\langle z,\mathcal{F}v\rangle_{\mathcal{Z}}=\langle \mathcal{F}^*z,v\rangle_{\mathcal{V}},$$
for all $v\in\mathcal{V}$ and $z\in\mathcal{V}$.

Now suppose that $f$ is a scalar function in $L_1[0,\infty)$, and the operator $Q$ on $L_2[0,\infty)$ is defined by 
$$(Qu)(t):=\int_0^\infty f(t-\tau)u(\tau)d\tau,$$
for $u$ in $L_2[0,\infty)$. How to show that the adjoint vector $Q^*$ is 
$$(Q^*z)(t):=\int_t^\infty f^*(\tau-t)z(\tau)d\tau,$$
for $z$ in $L_2[0,\infty)$, where $f^*$ denotes the complex conjugate of function $f$.

In order to show this, I need to prove that $$\langle z,Qu\rangle=\langle Q^*z,u\rangle,$$ where $\langle x,y\rangle:=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^*(t)y(t)dt$. But I cannot get the result following this.

Comment: Sorry, this problem is a bit difficult for me. Could you please give me some suggestions?

Comment: Start with the _definition_ of the adjoint - figure out what you need to prove...

Comment: Thanks, I have added some more explanations, also my effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is what I met when reading the book [*A course in robust control theory*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-3290-0). The result is provided but not giving the proof.

However, I find this result may not be correct. The adjoint vector of $Q^*$ should be in this way:
$$(Q^*z)(t):=\int_0^\infty f^*(\tau-t)z(\tau)d\tau.$$